# How to update progress bar as the program progresses on in PyQt in python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am working on a GUI program in pyqt5. I am thinking of putting a progress bar into to GUI that is going to be updated as the program progresses. As i testes that, it does not update dynamically and i searched for that and now i understand it needs to be written in worker thread. My program have 5 steps and after finishing each step i want to update progress bar by 20%. I really appreciate answers which solve my problem.

```
class MyAPP(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Action.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask)
        self.show()


    def runLongTask(self):
       
        Execute step 1
        Update progress bar by 20%

        Execute step 2
        Update progress bar by 40%

        Execute step 3
        Update progress bar by 60%

        Execute step 4
        Update progress bar by 80%

        Execute step 5
        Update progress bar by 100%

        
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyAPP()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: for a while it was my question too. It would be very helpful if anyone answers it

Comment: What about https://pythonpyqt.com/pyqt-progressbar/?

Comment: updating the GUI from a thread will crash your application ... you should check how to use threads properly in PyQT if you are going to do any work that takes more than a few milliseconds, orelse your next question will be "my application crashes and i don't know why"

Comment: @BlackBeans That was a really good help. But i want to call several times in program. For example when the program finishes to step1, progress bar should be updated, then step 2 executes and when step 2 ends, again progress bar should be updated. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: What's wrong with the example? Just use `pbar.setValue(something)` where `pbar` is your progress bar and `something` is the progression, just as in the example.

Comment: @BlackBeans The examples are ok but is not the same as mine. It those examples every thing is done in thread but in my example every thing is executing in main thread, i mean four steps are in the main thread and i only need to update progress bar after each step is finished

Comment: @Orca it depends on what you're *actually* doing in those "steps". If they are CPU bound (computations requiring long time to complete), then you *could* call `QApplication.processEvents()` at each step (and, possibly, periodically within each step, to avoid UI freezing); otherwise, for example while waiting for network replies, you should use QThreads and signals as shown in the example.

Comment: @musicamante it is about computations that require long time. As you said. i think i should use ```QApplication.processEvents()``` to pause the main thread and update progress bar and then continue.

Comment: @musicamante should i use any command after ```QApplication.processEvents()```? i mean after step 1, i should put ```QApplication.processEvents()``` and then what should i do? should i put any command to continue?

Comment: @Orca no, `processEvents()` doesn't stop anything: as the [documentation explains](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents), it "Processes some pending events": Qt, as almost any UI toolkit, works with an event loop that constantly waits for events in its *queue* and processes them. When a function is called in the main thread, the event loop is "stopped" until the function returns. This means that the event loop cannot process its events, including those responsible of *drawing* the UI. `processEvents()` tells the loop to process events that have been placed in its queue.

Comment: @Orca so, yes, you have to call it anytime you need to update the UI in order to show its changes (which is the case of updating a progress bar). But be aware, you shouldn't do it *too* often (as the docs say: "You can call this function **occasionally** when your program is busy performing a long operation"), and it also only has effect for events in the calling thread, so you shall not call it in a QThread if you want it to update the UI (it wouldn't make sense anyway): to do that, you should eventually put a small `sleep()` in that thread, releasing temporary control to the main thread.

Comment: @musicamante I really appreciate your perfect descriptions. i got the point. thank you very much for all of your descriptions